# Minimal prime numbers (no shorter subsequence of digits is prime)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

I need help with [minimal prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_prime_%28recreational_mathematics%29), defined as primes such that no shorter subsequence of digits is prime.

I calculated the prime numbers I need, but can not find a way to find minimal prime numbers. On the Wikipedia page stated that there are exactly 26 minimal primes. But how are those numbers calculated? Can you give me a formula and/or an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things about primes and digits almost always amount to brute force. That's because base $10$ (or any base) is essentially an arbitrary system for representing numbers.

Here, you have that every digit must be from $0,1,4,6,8,9$. Then you start eliminating:

- The number can't have $3+$ digits with have two or more digits $1$ because $11$ is prime (except when the number is $11$.
- The number can't be a $3+$-digit number with a $1$ before a $9$, because $19$ isn't prime
- ...

It's really a dull argument.

For example, if a $3+$ digit number contains a $1$, then the $1$ has to be the last digit (since the last digit must be $1$ or $9$, and a $1$ cannot come before a $9$.)

Since $41$ and $61$ and $2,3,5,7$ are prime, the only other digits that can occur are $9$ and $0$. Since $991$ is prime, there can't be more $9$s than $1$ for any other minimal prime, and since $9001$ is prime, there can't be more than one nine and two zeros. So that's all the minimal primes containing a digit $1$.

It might be work trying a simpler case - base $6$, say.

$2,3,5$ are still minimal primes in base $6$.

Any prime that does not contain those digits ends in $1$.

There is only one $2$-digit base $6$ prime not containing $2,3,5: 11_6=7$.

For three digits or mre, it must end in $1$ and contain only $0,4$ before. $401_6,441_6$ are both composite. So there are no $3$-digit minimal primes.

Next we try $4$-digits: $4401_6=1009$ and $4441_6$ are prime.

There is only two $5$-digit number we can check now: $40441_6=5353$ is not prime.
$40041_6=5209$ is prime.

$111_8=73_10, $401_8=257_{10}, $ is prime. $

Comment: 19 isn't a prime number? And what do you mean with "The number can't be a 3+-digit number"? Thank you.

Comment: There can't be a number with three or more digits and a $1$ before a $9$. $19$ is not a number with $3$ or more digits, so it doesn't break this rule. (Indeed, $19$ is the reason for the rule.)

Comment: Oh, now I got you. Thank you.

Comment: If I have a number 991 (which is minimal prime) Why can't I write it like 9, 99, 19, 91? 19 is prime so, why 991 is still a minimal prime?

Comment: A subsequence is ordered. @MxUser127 Think of it as being allowed to delete any digits, not re-order the ones that remain.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks. But I want the minimal primes in base 10. But thanks for an example. I will take a look at my project and I will ask for help I have questions. Otherwise I will accept the answer.

Previously you said it's a dull argument. Maybe it is, but not for me. I'm trying to code this thing. If you have any other "rules" for eliminating numbers please write them. Thank you again.